# Undesired Mouseover Effects When Using an iPad or Other Mobile Device

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, ipad

I'm working on a responsive website. There is one type of navigation element that is an clickable image link. I've got many of these on the page.  On a normal desktop computer when you mouseover this image it changes color (+ more), and changes back when you mouseout.  When clicked, you are linked to a new webpage.  Right now this is coded via a simple JavaScript Event handler.

```
<a href="http://myfakewebsite.com/next_page_1.html">
       <img onmouseover="{ this.src = 'image_1_red.png'; }" 
            onmouseout="{ this.src='image_1_normal.png'; }"
        src='image_1_normal.png'
       />
</a>
```

The issue is when a iPad user taps a clickable event, the following elements are sent.. mouseover, mousemove, mousedown, mouseup and click.  And that mouseover event is definitely causes me troubles. There is a fraction of a second where the image_1_normal image disappears and you get a visible icon (white question mark in box with blue background and white border) for a period of time before the site snaps to the new URL.  There is not enough time for the image_1_red to appear.  The whole affect looks odd. Its noticeable enough that my customer isn't happy.  Is there any way to mitigate this issue?  Is there a way in JavaScript to say...

`if this is a mobile touch device, then skip the whole mouseover thing`?

Is there a way to do this inline via Event Handler, or am i going to have to create event listeners for all of the elements in script en mass?

So I did an update to code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);

    function init() {

        var image_1 = document.getElementById("image_1_nav");
        var image_2 = document.getElementById("image_2_nav"); .. etc... 

        if (!("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement)){
            image_1.addEventListener("onmouseover", function(){
               this.src="image_1_red.png";}, false);
        }

        if ("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement){
            alert( "Mobile device with Touchstart"); }
    }
</script>
```

The alert test works fine on ipad not on desktop as expected.

Now I'm unable to get the onmouseover function to register... 
First off, the system didn't like    `if (!"ontouchstart" in document.documentElement){`  I had to change that to `if(!("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement)){` before it would register correctly. I'm now stuck trying to figure out why I can't see the event listeners for onmouseover....

Comment: Try `image_1.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){` (remove the `on`)

Comment: I figured that out a few hours ago.  Many thanks for your reply.  My intent was to complete my project to meet my deadline, then post an answer to my own question if nobody else got there first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from what I can see, there appears to be no way to use an 'inline' event handler to avoid OnMouseOver when a website is viewed on a mobile device.  This code seems to work:

```
<a href="http://myfakewebsite.com/next_page_1.html"><img src='image_1_normal.png' /></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);

    function init() {

        var image_1 = document.getElementById("image_1_nav");
        var image_2 = document.getElementById("image_2_nav"); //.. etc... 

        if (!("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement) && 
            ! (navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0) &&
            ! (navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0) ){
            image_1.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
               this.src="image_1_red.png";}, false);

            image_1.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
               this.src="image_1.png";}, false);             // .. etc... 
        }   
    }
</script>
```

So on a mobile device (iPad) the original image never gets modified at all during a click, No weird momentary popup icons, no miffed customers.    Oh, and many thanks to Manuel Ignacio López Quintero  [for this blog entry.](http://miloq.blogspot.com/2011/05/detect-touch-devices-javascript.html) and Patrick H. Lauke and Robert Nyman for their [article on detecting touch.](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/04/detecting-touch-its-the-why-not-the-how/)